# Получение высоты текста

Tags: winapi

Здравствуйте!

Есть комбо-бокс в котором мы самостоятельно рисуем список элементов. В общих чертах это делается так: имеется высота списка, вычисляется высота одной строки, высота списка делится на высоту строки, получаем кол-во строк для отображения и рисуем их с помощью DrawText

```
::DrawText(hdc, str, -1, &rcItem, DT_SINGLELINE | DT_VCENTER);
```

Высота одной строки строки сейчас определяется так:

```
int nHeight = ::DrawText(hDC, "ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ", -1, &rc, 0
                             | DT_LEFT
                             | DT_EDITCONTROL
                             | DT_NOPREFIX
                             | DT_WORDBREAK
                             | DT_CALCRECT
                             | DT_NOCLIP
                             | DT_SINGLELINE
                            );
```

Хотя я пытался и так:

```
SIZE sz = {0};
::GetTextExtentPoint32(hDC, "ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ", 26, &sz);
```

Результат был одинаковый.

Проблема в том, что возвращаемое этими функциями значение для высоты больше, чем высота текста (видимо, добавляется еще какой-то отступ). В результате, когда отображается список, он получается больше чем надо.

На первой картинке стандартный виндовый комбо-бокс, на второй наш, переделанный.

[image: Вот как выглядит список в стандартном виндовом комбо-боксе]
[image: А вот так выглядит список в нашем переделанном комбо-боксе]

Если отнять от получаемого значения(nHeight) 2, то высота строк в комбо-боксах совпадет. Но, во-первых, я не уверен, что на любом мониторе отображение будет работать правильно, а во-вторых мне не хочется использовать магические константы в коде.

Честно говоря, я не смог найти в гугле можно ли как-то получить эту "двойку". Может быть это какой-нибудь system metrics, но, видимо он мне не по глазам. Может быть кто-нибудь знает, откуда берутся вертикальные отступы от текста при вызове ::DrawText? И если я все же напишу в коде цифру, то не получится ли так, что на некоторых мониторах будут неверно отображаться элементы списка?

Comment: О размерах шрифта можно почитать тут [MSDN Character Widths](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/dd183418(v=vs.85).aspx) и вот https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/dd145122(v=vs.85).aspx

Comment: У окна есть ещё "ширина границы" (самой черты). Возможно вам ёё нужно учесть.

Comment: Спасибо за помощь! Статья "String Widths and Heights" привела меня к методу GetTextMetrics и это похоже то, что мне нужно.